# kotlin dotenv doesn't take directory configuration

Tags: android, kotlin, dotenv

Trying to use kotlin-dotenv, but this is not working, using kotlin object class, to manage singleton

Got error `Could not find /asset/env on the classpath`  whereas the env file is in /assets folder as mentionned in the doc

```
object EnvVariables {
    val envVar: Dotenv =
        dotenv {
            directory = "/assets"
            filename = "env"
    }
}

object RetrofitInstance {

    val api: TodoService by lazy {
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(EnvVariables.envVar["BASE_URL"])
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(TodoService::class.java)

    }
}
```

[image: env in assets folder]

[image: Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the doc is not accurate

In file DotEnvReader.java

```
return ClasspathHelper
            .loadFileFromClasspath(location.replaceFirst("./", "/"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

So, you can fix it by adding "."

```
var dotenv = dotenv {
    directory = "./assets" //use ./ instead of /
    filename = "env"
}
```